# Cycling gloves sizes

Tags: gloves

I am willing to buy some cycling gloves from an online store, but can't seem to find any details about the sizes. They range from S to XXL, but how do I know which best fits my hands? If it helps, I am willing to buy the Cube Teamline gloves.

Comment: Are you saying that these are what you're looking at: http://www.cube.eu/en/accessoires/gloves/ ?

Comment: Yes, the first ones.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try some other gloves in a store, to see what size fits you on average.

E.g. in a shirt I'm a medium or a large.

However I bought my gloves in a store, after looking at the whole range on display, and trying on a few of them for feel.

They 'fit me like a glove'.

When I was looking for winter gloves (with full-length fingers and an inner lining, which are more difficult to fit that finger-less gloves are), in an outdoor sports store with a cycling-clothing department, I found a great variation in the quality of the design, and in the quality of the manufacturing (i.e. the stitching).

Most I tried were not comfortable. I chose the best for me.

Comment: But are different brands' sizes matching? If an L matches my hand, maybe the gloves from Cube will be loose.

Comment: @linkyndy I edited my answer above, to try to address your comment.

Comment: So, since I don't have any physical store to try the gloves, I will probably send an e-mail to the Cube support team, maybe they'll send a size chart or something. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Maybe they provide a sizing chart online, where you can measure around your hands at the knuckle and determine the appropriate glove size.  Otherwise, you might be better off buying gloves locally, so you can try them on.

Comment: This. Any store that doesn't have this or won't provide it? Maybe they're a great store, but I'd buy the gloves elsewhere.

Comment: I searched for an online chart, but with no luck. I know, Neil, but there are only a few stores in my country from where I can buy these gloves, so it's not a solution to move to the next store because...there is hardly any next store :)

Answer (score 2):

There are somethings that are best bought localy.The variation in sizes of shoes,gloves and helmets between brands makes trial fitting almost a necessity.Some online sellers do a better job than others of helping you decide if someones product runs true to size.Contact the sellers customer service department for guidance. If they have product ratings check them as it is often the reason for comments.

Comment: I will contact them. Unfortunately, my country has very few specialized bicycle shops, therefore this set of gloves is not available in the only bike shop in my town.

Comment: Maybe your town has very few bicycle shops because you buy your gear online, instead of supporting your local shops?

Comment: No, not at all. The reason for this is because people don't care about bikes, the city is not very adequate for riding bikes and because people don't spend such amounts of money on bikes, they prefer to buy cheap bikes, stolen from other countries. This is the situation...